# Correctly using callbacks to wait for query completion

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, callback

I'm trying to make a reusable piece of code that queries a database (with some parameters), then performs action on this data and returns some newly created data. What I have roughly looks like this:

```
function loadList(config) {
    var list = [];

    var queryString = "SOME QUERY STRING BASED ON THE config PARAMETER";

    connection.query(queryString, function (err, result) {
        if err throw err;

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            //Perform some action on the data
            //IMPORTANT this changes the list variable
        }
    });

    return list;
}
```

Now, this code doesn't work, the function will in pretty much every case return `[]`. That is because `return list` is executed long before the callback from the query has ran. However, I can't for the love of god figure out how to structure my code that the `return list` of the *parent* function runs *after* the query and callback both ave executed. It might be because I'm tired, but I really can't see the solution to it.

I have thought of making a new callback function inside `loadList()` that is called from within the query, but if I call `return list` from within that callback, it will only return `list` for that callback, not the parent function.

What is the correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use callback base functions, like this:

```
function loadList(config, callback) {

    // check that callback is not null
    callback = callback || function() {};

    var list = [];

    var queryString = "SOME QUERY STRING BASED ON THE config PARAMETER";

    connection.query(queryString, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {}

        // after you done your work call the call back
        return callback(null, list);
    });
}
```

Usage :

```
loadList(config_here, function(err, list) {
    if (err) {
        // do something with err
    }

    // here you have the list
})
```

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tip. This callback base function, what does it roughly look like? Something like `function coolCallback(err, list) {//code here}`? What is the idea behind passing `err` to the callback?

Edit: Your edit made it clear! Thanks!

Comment: In modules it better to give `err` to caller of the module, and that function decide what to do with error, `throw` it, `print` it or etc.

Comment: I am facing the same issue but didn't get that why are you using "null" as a first parameter in return callback(null, list);